# How does one change the title of any window in X?

Tags: x11, xorg, openbox

I would like to know if it is possible to put an arbitrary name as window title
for any application in X or OpenBox. And if it is, How to do it or just a nice link to some documentation which I have been unable to find.
I don't like icons in my panel (currently tint2) but not all window title are
sufficient since most of the time they don't give the application name and are not pretty, for example Firefox has the title of the current web page which is not always pretty and does not give the name of the application itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[xdotool(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xdotool.1.html) can do that.  To rename whatever window you click next:

```
xdotool selectwindow set_window --name "new name"
```

To find a window based on its current name, then rename it:

```
xdotool search --name "old name" set_window --name "new name"
```

However, this won't last for any application (such as Firefox) that keeps updating its own name.  The way to prevent that will be specific to each application.

Comment: Is there an X11 tool to wait for window name change, e.g. to set appropriate icon?

Comment: This fails for non-ASCII title.

Comment: @user1274247 That's a [xdotool limitation](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/420). The comments on that ticket include some workarounds.